# Can I make it so the uesr's browser will cache an MVC3 page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have pages that stay the same from week to week. Every time a user requests them they are regenerated again.

I have set up the following for static:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Is there something that I can do to make the dynamic pages also cache?

Answer (score 3):

This is not set on your pages (Views) but on your Actions.
There is an [OutputCache ActionFilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) you can use:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```